# Its possible to open a windows CMD without preexisting sessions in python?

Tags: python, windows, session, terminal

I'm building a MVP application that collects data from Azure through the windows terminal. Basically, I currently need to log in and log out every time that I need to connect to a new account.
So, it's possible to create multiple terminals via python without context / preexisting sessions? Where I would log in to one account for each window and would keep all sessions coexisting at the same time?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to open the command prompt window using python?

Comment: Yes, The program is integrated using Python.